# HTTP 405 - After deploying GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, deployment, gwt-rpc

I followed the steps [showed here](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/comment-page-1/#comments) and deployed my GWT app on the tomcat 7 server.
When I run it, it gives me the HTTP 405 error. When I run the same app in deploy mode it just runs fine, but when I try to deploy on tomcat and run I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you compile your java code using GWT compile so that it gets converted to Javascript, and then create the war file.

Comment: and the other mistake what I did was I was using the url - http://localhost:8080/<appname>/<url pattern from web.xml>, instead of http://localhost:8080/<appname>/foo.html